# Javascript doesn't work for the users except System admin in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

i made some changes on a JavaScript which is hosted in my sharepoint. But the changes don't work for All users except System admin. Any help?

Here's the code:

```
Change.Track = function (FileName, verM, verMin, ListName, urlSite) {
        var fileMaj = "", ficMin = "", verM, verM;
        var data = Get.FileVersions(FileName);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].version.split(".")[1] === verMin || data[i].version.startsWith("@")) {
                fileMin = data[i].url
                verMin = data[i].version;
            }
            else if (data[i].version === verMaj || data[i].version === "0.1") {
                fileMaj = data[i].url
                verMaj = data[i].version;
            }
        }

        var title = "TrackChanges"
        var url = Get.config.urlSiteWeb.toString() +
        "/_Layouts/TrackChange/changes.aspx?fileMaj=" +
        fileMaj + "&fileMin=" + fileMin + "&listName=" + ListName + "&urlSite=" +
        urlSite + "/" + "&verMaj=" + verMaj + "&verMin=" + verMin;


        window.open(url, "_blank");

        // var d = Get.AfficheModal(encodeURIComponent(url), title);
        // var f = d.get_frameElement();
        //f.src = url;
    };

I only add that line to the script so the page can open in a new windows

window.open(url, "_blank");
```

Then i commented theses lines

```
    // var d = Get.AfficheModal(encodeURIComponent(url), title);
    // var f = d.get_frameElement();
    //f.src = url;
```

its work only when am logged as admin. All the users have access to the library where the script is hosted

Comment: What happens exatly? The new version of the script is not loaded? There's a JavaScript error? The page "changes.aspx" (a custom page of your own?) raises an error ?

Comment: The new line that i've added will allow the page to open in a new window. but its work only when am logged in as an admin not with a normal user. it doesn't open in a new windows for a normal user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where's your JavaScript file hosted?
If it's in a SharePoint document library (like "Site Assets" or else), it may be that the file is not published/approved.
Check whether the doc lib has versioning enabled, and publish the file as a major version (+ approve it if needed).

Comment: Hi thank for your answer. The script is hosted in Style in Library/scripts/ on my Sharepoint Website. A major version of the script is published.